# How to get multiple Scrapy spiders to parse a list of URL links at the same time?

Tags: python, scrapy, multiprocessing

I've got a list of about 1000 URL's and I need to extract the same kind of data from each one. Is there a way to get Scrapy to "deploy" multiple spiders at once to each take a URL from the list and parse the page and then output to a common dictionary? I'm thinking of using 10 or more spiders to do this.

Comment: does anybody bother reading [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to solve the task without using multiple spiders?

Try to just add all the URLs to 'start_urls' list or get the list of URLs from file in 'start_requests' method and adjust the level of concurrency using Srapy`s settings such as 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' and 'CONCURRENT_ITEMS', like:

```
custom_settings = {
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': '1000',
    'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': '10000'
}
```

Or something which fits your tasks more.

P.S. Generating a number of Scrapy spiders from the list of URLs and running them concurrently with scrapy-deploy (http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is also an option, although it looks like a little dirty as for me.

Comment: Yeah I figured the best way to do this would be to put all the URl's in start_urls. I didn't know about the concurrency though. The default value looks to be 16. I tried this with a list of 30 URL's and it still take like 5-10 seconds to request and scrape. Would 1000 requests be too many do have at once? I've got about 11,000 URL's.

Comment: >"I didn't know about the concurrency though"
You should definitely look at the list of Scrapy settings (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) if you haven't yet. There are different concurrency settings there (per domain, per IP, etc) which you can try changing to get the best performance.


>"Would 1000 requests be too many do have at once?"
I don't know exactly, but I think that heavily depends on your machine specs and Internet connection. Also you can try dividing the list of URL's into e.g. 4 scripts and run them by scrapy-deploy for better concurrent processing.

Comment: I thought that scrapy takes your script and the bottleneck isn't the individual spiders but at the actual main scrapy script? So running 4 separate scripts won't doe much. Although it won't hurt to try.

Comment: I`m telling not about Scrapy itself, but about scrapy-deploy (or Scrapyd) - it spawns a new Scrapy process for each spider (http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#how-scrapyd-works), so you can gain some profit from processing feed in a few processes. Crawling is not CPU-bound usually, but in your case it can be a problem too (I have only around 20-30 spiders now and they take all CPU resources for an almost 2 hours when scraping starts on our server with Intel Xeon E3-1275 v5), so you should definitely try it